# unable to pass values from multiple parent object for mapping through mapstruct

Tags: mapstruct

I am mapping a scenario where one object of a parent class need to mapped at child level.Now I am unable to pass that object parameter through mapping method.

```
Mapper class:

@Mapping(target = "segment", source = "flightSegment")
@Mapping(target = "PTC", source = "passengerFlight")
Itinerary mapProductAirToItinerary(ProductAir productAir);

List<PTC> mapPassengerFlightToPTC(List<PassengerFlight> passengerFlight);

@Mapping( target = "code", source = "passengerTypeCode")
@Mapping( target = "numberOfPassengers", source = "passengerQuantity")
@Mapping( target = "id", source = ***unknown***)
PTC createSOAPTCfromODflightProduct(PassengerFlight passengerFlight);
```

In this above mapping ProductAir has a string object called ID which is required to be mapped in the method createSOAPTCfromODflightProduct with the target id. Here I have kept is as unknown as I am unable to pass the value of productAir.id to it through mapPassengerFlightToPTC and createSOAPTCfromODflightProduct mapping method. Is there anyway I can pass the value from parent level to child mapping level?
The structure of product air is given below, SO I want to map the id ->p0 with the id of PTC object

```
"@type": "ProductAir",
      "totalDuration": "PT3H54M",
      "id": "p0",
      "FlightSegment": [
        {
          "id": "s1",
          "sequence": 1,
          "Flight": {
            "@type": "Flight",
            "duration": "PT3H54M",
            "carrier": "AA",
            "number": "2793",
            "operatingCarrier": "AA",
            "operatingCarrierName": "American Airlines",
            "equipment": "738",
            "id": "f1",
            "Departure": {
              "@type": "Departure",
              "location": "DEN",
              "date": "2020-07-09",
              "time": "23:40:00"
            },
            "Arrival": {
              "@type": "Arrival",
              "location": "MIA",
              "date": "2020-07-10",
              "time": "05:34:00"
            }
          }
```

Comment: Not clear from above. Is `ProductAir` a member of `PassengerFlight` or is this a separate parameter?

Answer (score 1):

so.. you could try this:

```java
@Mapping(target = "segment", source = "flightSegment")
@Mapping(target = "PTC", source = "passengerFlight")
Itinerary mapProductAirToItinerary(ProductAir productAir, @Context String id);

List<PTC> mapPassengerFlightToPTC(List<PassengerFlight> passengerFlight, @Context String id);

@Mapping( target = "code", source = "passengerTypeCode")
@Mapping( target = "numberOfPassengers", source = "passengerQuantity")
@Mapping( target = "id", ignore = true )
PTC createSOAPTCfromODflightProduct(PassengerFlight passengerFlight, @Context String id);

@AfterMapping
default void createSOAPTCfromODflightProduct(PassengerFlight passengerFlight, @MappintTarget PTC target, @Context String id) {
     target.setId( id );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer Sjaak. You also asked one question which I haven't answered. So actually PassengerFlight is a member of ProductAir . The structure of the source (ProductAir) is given above in the actual question.